# Raye Penber's fiancée's part opens up a loophole in DeathNote

Tags: death-note

***Raye Penber's fiancée*** who had come to give the tip about Kira (she deduced most of the Kira's tactics even before L!), and Light Yagami's encounter was missed by the receptionist/L at the police head quarters.

Both were seen discussing about telling her theory to Light's father in front of the two receptionist before she became missing. Most police head quarters have CCTV cameras attached, so it should have been used by the police to get a clue about her before she went missing the day she visited the police. If she was alive after that day, she would have tried to visit the police head quarters again.

As per receptionists/ CCTV cameras she was last seen with Light and Light offering her to give the tip, so he can on behalf of her tell it to his father, even offering his phone. At least the initial investigation should have started with interrogating Light about her. How was this scenario missed by L and his Team? Is this not a goof?

Comment: Your theory is quite hard to understand. Maybe consider adding screenshots showing your point

Comment: Just because L is super smart, doesn't mean he would not miss anything. Otherwise, he wouldn't lose to Kira.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To L and the investigators, Naomi Misora is only missing

> Light writes down Naomi's name, resulting in her death by suicide. Her body is never found due to the specifications made by Light in the Death Note.

Source: [Naomi Misora - Plot (Last Paragraph)](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Naomi_Misora#Plot)

Given that Light specified that she would commit suicide and when L sees Naomi's photo they still don't know that Kira can kill besides a heart attack, there's no way to connect Naomi's disappearance to Kira.

If L was to take a leap of faith and pull out the CCTV footage showing Light with Naomi, what can they do then? Light had a legitimate reason for being at Police Headquarters (in fact it was by pure chance that Light ran into her there, it wasn't planned like with Raye) and if they questioned him, Light could just as easily said he noticed that she seemed depressed and tried to help her which would backup the suicide if they discovered her body.

Comment: Also I missed out a part , got the point by reading the anime where Light knows that the CCTV cameras would not be able to capture them together in the reception. Thanks every one answering the question!

Answer (score 1):

The more pertinent question is why Raye Penber would show his ID to Light in the first place considering L secretly tapped the FBI to help with the investigation. L didn't want the Japanese police to know he was investigating them since it would cause friction, and the FBI was aware of this which is why they were there in secret. Thus, the FBI agent would have avoided showing the DEPUTY SUPERINTENDENT'S SON his ID at all costs to make sure their presence in Japan remained a secret.

This is the only plothole I've seen in the show that makes no sense. Other than that, it seems like a perfect story!

Answer (score 0):

L probably did not notice any of it because:

1. He did not automatically remember her name, and
2. If L would have found that and saw that Light was the last one with her while she was alive, he *could* have arrested him. However, they were in a *big* city, so they wouldn't have had evidence that it was **Light** that killed her. Also, if L *did* arrest him, the entire story would have been shorter and not as fun as it is now.

Answer (score 0):

But Light did kill other criminals (he states so in ep. 7) using suicide, so L should have at least suspected this possibility and then confirmed his theory when he finds out that Raye Penber's wife goes missing, him knowing that she was previously an FBI agent.

He should have then checked where she was seen last and then connected the dots to Kira. Light may be able to talk his way out of this but L should at least question/suspect him of this incident.

Comment: It seems like this is a comment to the accepted answer, and not an answer to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Well I dont think its a loophole. They wouldn’t have know she visited the police station so why would they check the cctv? The receptionist also did not know this woman’s name so they wouldn’t know she was Rey’s wife.